# What will netbeans IDE do when I press Ctrl+F6 to run a java file?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have no idea of how Netbeans IDE run a java file.

Firstly, it would ensure the .class file is up-to-date.

Then, execute the class. But from where (working directory) and with which command (parameter)?

I observe difference on how relative path is located when I run the java file from Netbeans IDE and when I run using Windows command prompt (i.e > `java pack.age.name.ClassName`)

Comment: is the project a 'standard' NetBeans project (which is ant based) or a  Maven based project?

Answer (score 2):

You can find that out by putting this at the start of the main method of the class:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

It looks like it will run from the directory that the project is in (eg. ....\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1)

You cannot specify command line arguments for a single class (that I am aware of).  To do that you have to use the Project | Properties (and there you can also set the working directory).

I would suggest that you do not write code that depends on the working directory if you can avoid it though...

Answer (score 1):

You can get informative results by running the project's `build.xml` from the command line in verbose mode: `ant -verbose run`. Look for the `[java]` command options under `run:`. Typing `ant -p` will show you the available targets.